# Как импортировать юнит тест mocha из пакета meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, mocha

Мое приложение с использованием Meteor.js полностью разбито по пакетам, в одном из пакетов есть файл **security-ui.tests.js** далее который указывается в **package.js**

```
Package.onTest((api) => {
api.use('astropos:security-ui');
api.use('cultofcoders:mocha@2.4.6');
api.mainModule('security-ui.tests.js')})
```

Также есть модуль **tests/main.js**

запускаю тест таким образом:

```
meteor test --driver-package cultofcoders:mocha --full-app
```

модуль **test/main.js** отрабатывает, а вот **security-ui.tests.js** запускаться не хочет. как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо **Package.*onTest*** необходимо использовать **Package.*onUse***

```
   Package.onUse(function(api) {
      api.use('cultofcoders:mocha')
      api.use('practicalmeteor:sinon')
      api.use('practicalmeteor:chai')

      api.addFiles(security-ui.tests.js', 'client') })
```